# Strange issue with fixed div scroll up

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am experiencing a strange issue with fixing a div, inside which there are other divs.

What I want to achieve is; When I scroll, hide the `.slideshow_head` div and only `.menu` to stay visible and move to top.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong as I thought that if I fix the `.header` div, all divs inside it will move up with it. However, the `.menu` div does not move up but just stay fixed.

```
window.onscroll=function () {
    var top = window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

       if(top > 50){document.getElementById("menu").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.height="0px"
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.height="40px"
        }  

if(top > 50){document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("header").style.height="140px"
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("header").style.height="390px"
        }

        if(top > 50){document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.height="0px"

        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.height="390px"

        }
}
```

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/largan/P2B93/

Any advices?

Comment: why have you repeated the same `ifs` over and over again?

Comment: Well, cos one of the div's (.header) should not be hidden completely, just 200px of it. I have tried to use only one if for the .header but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in this portion:

```
      if(top > 50){document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.position = "fixed";
      document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("header").style.height = "0px";
      document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("slideshow_head").style.height = "0px";
      document.getElementById("header_holder").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("header_holder").style.height = "0px";
```

Comment: It doesn't work... once you scroll the .header hide and never comes back.

Comment: Why is top > 50?? If you set a console.log(top); in your onscroll function it looks like you want to make the top less than like 5 or so.

So building on the last comment:
if (top>50){ 
} else if (top < 5) {
and then whatever code needs to be executed to show the menu again.
}